# Rails 7 - how can I update Labels ( implemented with Enums ) without refreshing the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a table that shows the status which I implemented using Enums [image]

and I can even change the status to whatever I want
[image]

So the problem is whenever I change the status, it refreshes the page and then the Labels change.

So how can I put in live action to badges so whenever I change the status(implemented using Enums), it does not need to refresh the page??

If I opened this table in two different Laptops and if I change status in one Laptop, it should automatically update the Labels in other Laptop as well without needing to refresh the page, how can I implement this Live Action feature to Labels?

Here is my code

`orders_controller.rb`

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_order, only: %i[show file_error success cancelled processing pending]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    include ActiveStorage::SendZip

    def file_error
        authorize @order
        @order.file_error!
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is having a file error for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"
        

    end

    def success
        authorize @order
        @order.success!
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is success for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"

    end

    def cancelled
        authorize @order
        @order.cancelled!
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is cancelled for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"
    end

    def processing
        authorize @order
        @order.processing!
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is processing for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"
    end

    def pending
        authorize @order
        @order.pending!
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is pending for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"
    end
        


    def universals
        @orders = Order.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per(5)
        authorize @orders
    end

    def download_files
        @order = Order.find(params[:id])
        authorize @order
        send_zip @order.files, filename: "#{@order.user.name + @order.id.to_s}.zip"
        @order.processing!
        flash[:alert] = "The Order is processing for #{@order.user.name } #OrderID: #{@order.id.to_s}"
    end
```

`views/shared/_table_details.html.erb`

```
<td class="px-6 py-4 text-gray-600">
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
        <span class="p-1 rounded-md <%= badges(order.status) %>"><%= order.status %></span>
        <div class="relative" data-controller="dropdown">
            
            <button type="button"
                    id="dropdown_example"
                    class="inline-flex justify-center items-center"
                    data-dropdown-target="button"
                    data-action="click->dropdown#toggle keydown.esc->dropdown#toggle click@window->dropdown#hide"
                    tabindex="0"
                    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-4 w-4 inline-block text-gray-500 hover:text-slate-700" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
                <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 5v.01M12 12v.01M12 19v.01M12 6a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2zm0 7a1 1 0 110-2 1 1 0 010 2z" />
                </svg>
            </button>

        
            <div role="menu"
                class="absolute right-0 origin-top-right w-48 shadow-xl rounded z-1 hidden"
                data-dropdown-target="menu"
                data-transition-enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                data-transition-enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                data-transition-enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                data-transition-leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                data-transition-leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                data-transition-leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="dropdown_example">
                <div class="bg-white rounded-md">
                <div class="p-1 space-y-1">
                    <%= link_to success_order_path(order), class:"flex items-center space-x-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-700" do %>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M4.5 12.75l6 6 9-13.5" />
                    </svg>

                    <span>Success</span>

                    <% end %>

                    <%= link_to cancelled_order_path(order), class:"flex items-center space-x-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-700" do %>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                    </svg>

                    <span>Cancel</span>

                    <% end %>

                    <%= link_to file_error_order_path(order), class:"flex items-center space-x-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-700" do %>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 9v3.75m9-.75a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0zm-9 3.75h.008v.008H12v-.008z" />
                    </svg>

                    <span>File Error</span>

                    <% end %>

                    <%= link_to processing_order_path(order), class:"flex items-center space-x-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-700" do %>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.023 9.348h4.992v-.001M2.985 19.644v-4.992m0 0h4.992m-4.993 0l3.181 3.183a8.25 8.25 0 0013.803-3.7M4.031 9.865a8.25 8.25 0 0113.803-3.7l3.181 3.182m0-4.991v4.99" />
                    </svg>

                    <span>Processing</span>

                    <% end %>

                    <%= link_to pending_order_path(order), class:"flex items-center space-x-2 rounded py-2 px-3 text-sm font-medium text-slate-600 hover:bg-slate-100 hover:text-slate-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-slate-100 focus:text-slate-700" do %>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.857 17.082a23.848 23.848 0 005.454-1.31A8.967 8.967 0 0118 9.75v-.7V9A6 6 0 006 9v.75a8.967 8.967 0 01-2.312 6.022c1.733.64 3.56 1.085 5.455 1.31m5.714 0a24.255 24.255 0 01-5.714 0m5.714 0a3 3 0 11-5.714 0" />
                    </svg>

                    <span>Pending</span>

                    <% end %>
                    
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: You can realise it using websockets (ActionCable or Turbo Stream)

Comment: my rails server stops if I use turbo_stream_from  on index page, maybe I am doing it wrong, can you help me with this stuff  ;' )

Comment: Create MCVE and someone help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for real-time updates as soon as data changes in the backend it should reflect in all places without refreshing the page. For this kind of feature, you can achieve via WebSocket. In Rails, you can use [ActionCable](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html) for this. Just try to implement and I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a `update.turbo_stream.erb` and use `turbo_stream_tag` to partially update the label without refreshing the entire page?
Need to define the `respond_to do |format|` block in your update action to accept turbo response.
Also, assuming you don't have something like `{ turbo: false }` in your label form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).